# Dokan Multivendor Store plugin create shortcode / function / button to vendor's store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode, dokan

I am trying to create a shortcode which I want to place on the single product pages. I created a product template with elementor and now I want to include a link out of a shortcode which leads the customer to the vendor's shop. I have written these lines so far but it will only bring the user to the same page as he is. What have I done wrong?

```
function dokan_shortcode_single_link() {
    ?>
<p><span class='details'>Hier geht es zum Store: <?php printf( '<a href="%s">Store Name</a>', esc_url( dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ) ), esc_html( $store_info['store_name'] ) ); ?></span></p>

<?php    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it myself by creating a custom code - in this case, I found some snippets on the web and adapted them. Finally, I created a shortcode to insert everywhere in my templates:

```
add_shortcode ( 'giveme_vendor_url_title', 'display_vendor_url_shortcode2', 20 );
function display_vendor_url_shortcode2() {
    // Get the author ID (the vendor ID)
    $vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_id() );
    // Get the WP_User object (the vendor) from author ID
    $vendor = new WP_User($vendor_id);

    $store_info  = dokan_get_store_info( $vendor_id ); // Get the store data
    $store_name  = $store_info['store_name'];          // Get the store name
    $store_url   = dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id );  // Get the store URL

    $vendor_name = $vendor->display_name;              // Get the vendor name
    $address     = $vendor->billing_address_1;           // Get the vendor address
    $postcode    = $vendor->billing_postcode;          // Get the vendor postcode
    $city        = $vendor->billing_city;              // Get the vendor city
    $state       = $vendor->billing_state;             // Get the vendor state
    $country     = $vendor->billing_country;           // Get the vendor country

    // Display the seller name linked to the store
    printf( '<h3>Alle Erlebnisse von <a href="%s">%s</a> entdecken</h3>', $store_url, $store_name );
}
```